# Can an nvme/m.2 card be adding as an additional drive to any motherboard?

Tags: ssd, motherboard, pci-express, nvme

I'm trying to expand my storage for a gaming pc, and have the option to get a Sandisk 3d ultra ssd or an nvme card for roughly the same price. I would have to buy an nvme to PCIE adapter, of course.

I cannot find a straightforward answer anywhere. Will I be able to add the nvme as an additional drive on an older Dell Optiplex 7020 with the PCIE adapter? I only have 1 PCIE 3.0 port that is being used by a GPU, so will it work with a PCIE 2.0 port? It's slower than 3.0 but I believe it's still faster than an SSD. SSD is 600mbps and NVME is 3.5gpbs, while PCIE 2.0 will bottle neck it at 2gbps I believe.

Comment: NVMe cards _are_ SSDs. Are you comparing them to **SATA** SSDs?

Comment: PCIE 2.0 x1 is 500 MB/sec which is the likely bandwidth that will be offered using an adapter card. So it would actually be slower than a SATA III SSD if that is true.

Comment: @user1686 Yes, with Sata SSDs. There are different devices though. NVME is not compatible with BIOS boot on older motherboards. So my question is if it is even possible to use it with an unsupported BIOS at all, not as a boot drive but as an extra drive.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks! So an nvme card is compatible with an unsupported motherboard (optiplex) via PCIE 2.0? I have a buddy who tried to use it as a boot drive and his optiplex motherboard didn't recognize it. I'm just trying to use it as an additional drive though.

Comment: Your unlikely going to be able to boot to any drive connected to a NVMe PCIe adapter card. If you want to boot off a SSD you should get a SATA SSD.  If your machine has BIOS firmware instead of UEFI then it will NOT work.

Comment: @SuperJayRay An NVMe drive would have the advantage that you would also be able to use it in a new computer if you get one with a suitable spare slot, and then it would run at its full speed. For Windows 7, if that's what the computer is running, you can download an NVMe driver.

Comment: An M.2 card can be added to any motherboard that has an M.2 slot. You can also buy a PCIe to M.2 adaptor and connect it that way, but it may be that you cannot boot from it (might need motherboard support) but the device should be usable within your OS.